# Join Django/Python list by commas then slugify each element

Tags: django

From a Python list:

```
categories = ["category 1", "category 2", "category 3"]
```

I want to generate a javascript array of category slugs like this:

```
var categories = ["category-1", "category-2", "category-3"];
```

I've tried both these, but it's yielding very inaccurate results:

```
var categories = ["{{ categories|join:'", "'|slugify }}"];
var categories = ["{{ categories|slugify|join:'", "' }}"];
```

So I guess my problem is not only the order of these filters, seems like I need to do something else but I don't know what I'm looking for exactly.

**NOTE**: I know how to do it in a loop, but I was hoping there's a one-liner for this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something you should do in the template - you should do it in the view and pass the slugified list.

Comment: I'm using the regular list on 2 other occasions in the template, so I would like to use the same variable

Comment: Then you should pass both.

Comment: Well if there's definitely no way of doing this on-the-fly in the template, I'll grudgingly do this hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

categories = [slugify(cat) for cat in categories]
```

and then:

```
var categories = {{ categories|safe }}
```

Comment: Since this is being passed to a JS script, it would be good to dump the list to JSON.

Comment: That is code to put in the views however, right? Not the template? So I would have to make a slugified duplicate of the variable since I'm also using the regular list for something else in the template?

Comment: Yes, you should put this in views. If you need regular list also, simply assign new list to another variable.

Comment: Thanks friend, I'll use your wise advice ;)